# Lua, Advancing to the next letter of the alphabet

Tags: string, lua

I am very surprised that I did not find this explicitly answered here in StackOverflow, or on the [Lua.org](http://www.lua.org/) Website

If

- My Lua variable contains a single letter, and
- I want the next letter in the alphabet

Then, how do I manipulate that variable to change from, say, "J" to "K" ?

I looked at [The String Library](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.html) in the [Lua.Org](http://www.lua.org/) website, and didn't see the word "alphabet" on any of the pages there

e.g.

```
 --------------------------------------------------
 --                                              --
 --    Func Name: Alphabetic_Advance_By_1        --
 --                                              --
 --    On Entry:  The_Letter contains one        --
 --               character. It must be a        --
 --               letter in the alphabet.        --
 --                                              --
 --    On Exit:   The caller receives the        --
 --               next letter                    --
 --                                              --
 --               e.g.,                          --
 --                                              --
 --               A will return B                --
 --               B will return C                --
 --               C will return D                --
 --                                              --
 --               X will return Y                --
 --               Y will return Z                --
 --               Z will return A                --
 --                                              --
 --                                              --
 --                                              --
 --------------------------------------------------



 function Alphabetic_Advance_By_1(The_Letter)

 local Temp_Letter

 Temp_Letter = string.upper(The_Letter)

 -- okay, what goes here ???


 return(The_Answer)

 end
```

Comment: `The_Letter = ('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA'):match(The_Letter..'(.)')`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Excellent, Sir.  I don't understand it at all, but it certainly works !

Comment: @user.1 Egor's answer, uses a Lua Pattern with the string.match function to find the letter in the list of letters and then uses the (.) to return the letter after the one you searched for.

Comment: Okay, so `:match` is part of the string library in Lua ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am very surprised that I did not find this explicitly answered here in StackOverflow, or on the Lua.org Website

It has to do with the character encodings used in your particular build of Lua, so it's beyond the scope of the Lua language proper.

You can use `string.byte` to get the byte(s) of a string. You can use `string.char` to turn bytes into a string.

Lua doesn't guarantee that the character codes for 'A' through 'Z' are contiguous, because C doesn't. You can't even be sure that each is encoded with a single byte.  If your implementation is using ASCII then each character is represented by a single byte value and you can add 1 get the next letter, but you shouldn't rely on this. For example, if Temp_Letter < 'Z':

```
 The_Answer = string.char(Temp_Letter:byte() + 1)
```

---

Here's a way to do this without relying on character encoding:

```
local alphabet = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
local index = alphabet:find(Temp_Letter)
if index then
    index = (index % #alphabet) + 1 -- move to next letter, wrapping at end
    TheAnswer = alphabet:sub(index, index)
end
```

Comment: Whoa, you are assuming that the alphabet is encoded with one byte per character. Of course, it's up the question asker to supply these details, including which language, script, character set and encoding need to be considered. Even then, I think your approach of hard-coding an alphabet sequence would still be required.

Comment: @TomBlodget I'm aware of the assumption and pointed it out myself ("relying on character encoding"). If the OP's build is using plain old ASCII (e.g. any of the builds he'd get from Lua.org), then the first example would work, and it illustrates how those functions work.  If he's got a Unicode string that doesn't happen to be a subset of UTF-8, then it will break horribly. If it'll make you feel better, I'll change my wording to more strongly suggest that relying on coding is a bad idea. :)

Comment: @Mud   This is educational for me.  I have only used 4 kinds of variables in Lua so far: Numeric, String, Boolean, and Nil. (Those are all I've ever needed.) Is alphabet a table ? I have some homework to do.  Plus one for your answer and comment both.

Comment: The alphabet is a string. Tables are where the real fun begins, though. :)

Comment: @User.1 Of course those are _value_ types; In Lua, _variables_ don't have types.

Comment: @Mud  Smirk, you are correct.  Lua is neat; "just another language" until you hit variables.